# Purple/Red Cabbage kashrut issues

Tags: kashrut-kosher, stringency-chumrah, vegetables

Funny thing happened to me tonight.
I was buying some falafel and noticed that they did not have any "purple cabbage" (a.k.a. red cabbage) as a side dish option.  I asked if they had any in back, and was told they are not allowed to have it because they are a mehadrin eatery.

Now, the Purple Cabbage in the store carries a mehadrin Hechsher, and when I asked about it further he said something about the pickles, or vinegar, I'm not sure which.

What Kashrut issue could there be with purple cabbage that would not exist with regular "sauerkraut", that the Mehadrin Rabanut would not allow this person to carry it in their Falafel-only stand?

Edit:
I guess the context wasn't very clear, but this is in Israel. The Rabanut of the city, in order to give a "Mehadrin" Hashgagcha requires that they don't use any "purple cabbage", (Which is Red cabbage mixed with mayonaise), but if they just wanted a regular "Kosher" status, then they could have used it.  They do allow the use of Regular white cabbage though, which has no mayonnaise and is pickled.

To further clarify

Allowed:

[image: Allowed]

Not Allowed:

[image: Not Allowed]

Comment: Even though the package says "kruv adom", they all call it "kruv segol" where I live :)

Comment: Did anyone notice the Bedatz Eidah Hachareidis on the package? Is Rabbanut Mehadrin more stringent than them?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the kashrut of the cabbage itself, but rather how it mixes with other items in the store. I'm not sure though.  But yes, the falafel guy laughed at the fact that the hashkagah on the cabbage is more "strict" than the hashgah he has for the whole stand.  He said something about the "Chamutz" but I couldn't quite understand what he was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues of infestation at times with red/purple cabbage.

http://usours.com/red-cabbage-infestation-839

http://matzav.com/kashrus-alert-infestation-in-fresh-red-cabbage

Comment: If one of those linked-to pages helps to answer the question (why there's more of an issue with cabbage in the falafel stand than in the grocery), could you synopsize that part of it, please?

Comment: Perhaps that falafal stand does not use those hashgachos?